# WebStorm using ES6 import with CommonJS module

Tags: webstorm

I'm using WebStorm and want to use ES6 import instead of require. However when using import with libraries that use CommonJS like lodash I get a warning from WebStorm "cannot resolve symbol".

The code work perfectly as babel transform the import to require, I just want WebStorm to play along and not showing any error. I don't want to partly use ES6 import and partly require.

I'm using WebStorm version 2016.2.2.

[image: Cannot resolve symbol castArray]

Comment: webstorm can resolve es6 imports from CommonJS modules, but just in cases when modules are exported explicitly, like `module.exports = module_name;` or similar; but lodash modules are exposed in a tricky way: ```var freeExports = typeof exports == 'object' && exports && !exports.nodeType && exports;
var freeModule = freeExports && typeof module == 'object' && module && !module.nodeType && module;
var moduleExports = freeModule && freeModule.exports === freeExports;
var _ = runInContext();
if (freeModule) {
    (freeModule.exports = _)._ = _;
    freeExports._ = _;
  }```.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful, so it just lodash issue. Can you make it an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webstorm can resolve es6 imports from CommonJS modules, but just in cases when modules are exported explicitly, like `module.exports = module_name;` or similar; but lodash modules are exposed in a tricky way:

```
var freeExports = typeof exports == 'object' && exports && !exports.nodeType && exports; 
var freeModule = freeExports && typeof module == 'object' && module && !module.nodeType && module; 
var moduleExports = freeModule && freeModule.exports === freeExports; 
...
var _ = runInContext(); 
...
if (freeModule) { (freeModule.exports = _)._ = _; freeExports._ = _; }
```

that's why WebStorm can't find modules there...

Comment: with Webstorm 2019.3.2 and ` "lodash": "^4.17.15"` it works out of the box, no workarounds required